# Associate Polynomials on an Integral Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, equivalence-relations

I am being asked to prove that two polynomials being associated in $R[x]$ is an equivalence relation.

That is, two polynomials are associated in $R[x]$ if $f,g \in R[x],$ and there exists a $\lambda \in R$ such that $ f = \lambda g$. Then, the equivalence relation would be $$f \sim g \iff f = \lambda g \text{ for some } \lambda \in R.$$

Now, it is very easy to prove this is an equivalence relation if $R$ is a field or ring with division (since for every $\lambda \neq 0,$ we have $\lambda^{-1}$). However, I am being asked to prove the equivalence relation for $R$ an integral domain, and here is where I am not sure if this is a mistake or if there is a way to do it. Do all integral domains have multiplicative inverses?

Is this a mistake? Or how would I go about this? My algebraic structures are a bit rusty. Thanks!

Comment: You probably want $\lambda$ to be unit in $R$? Did you misread to exercise statement?

Comment: It's necessary that we restrict $\lambda$: With the relation $\sim$ defined as in the question statement, $r \sim 1$ for all $r \in R \subset R[x]$ (just take $\lambda = r$, respectively). By symmetry $1 \sim r$ for all $r \in R$, but this says precisely that every element of $R$ has a multiplicative inverse. (N.b. even in the case that $R$ is a division ring, we need to restrict to $\lambda \neq 0$.)

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of "associates" should specify that $\lambda$ is a unit.

It turns out that when $R$ is a domain $U(R[X])=U(R)$, so that may explain why it did not talk about the units of $R[X]$.

As you've written, the relation is merely divisibility, which is obviously not always symmetric. That's what making $\lambda$ a unit buys for you.

> do all integral domains have multiplicative inverses?

I'm not clear on what you're asking. *domains* don't "have inverses," but their elements can. Some of them, or everything except $0$, depending on the domain.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain and thus $\mathbb{Z}\left[x \right]$ is also an integral domain. Take $f\left(x \right) = 3x +6$ and $g\left(x \right) = x +2$. Then $ f=3g$. But there is no $\lambda$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ g = \lambda f$. Hence the given relation need not be an equivalence relation on an integral domain.

Your claim for division rings and fields is correct.